# Why there are pip and conda packages after fresh installation?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

All

Windows 10, 64bit, d/l Anaconda 2.5.0 with Python3, 64bit and installed it

After fresh installation i type `conda list`, and, among packages, I see
duplicates like

```
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_1
jupyter-client            4.1.1                     <pip>
jupyter-console           4.1.0                     <pip>
jupyter-core              4.0.6                     <pip>
jupyter_client            4.1.1                    py35_0
jupyter_console           4.1.0                    py35_0
jupyter_core              4.0.6                    py35_0
```

Is it normal, and why some packages (not all of them, just a few) have
duplicates (not quite, there is `-` vs `_`) both in conda and pip?

What will happen if I do `pip uninstall jupyter-core`?

What should be policy toward such packages?

Comment: the reason is that you use conda and pip to install the same package, conda fails to separate them, I had the same problem and people suggest: to reinstall conda, and if you need pip to install something, use a new env and try there, do not use pip and conda for the root env at the sametime. I could not find a better solution,... let me know if you find a better way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a known problem with the output of conda. The packages are installed only once, but due to differing naming conventions, they are listed twice. There is a (now closed) bug report about it:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1237

When you ask `conda` for a list of packages, this is what happens (or used to happen):

- `conda` knows which packages were installed with `conda`.
- `conda` calls `pip` under the covers to find packages that were installed outside of `conda`.
- `pip` lists all packages, regardless of where they came from.
- `conda` filters the output of `pip` by removing the packages installed with `conda`.

Afaict, the problem is with `conda`-installed packages that contain an underscore. `pip` replaces underscores with hyphens in its output. Therefore, `conda` fails to detect that it's a package installed by itself, and lists it as installed by `pip`. Of course, `conda` also lists the package with its original, underscored name as installed by `conda`. Hence the duplicates.