# Why is conda installing packages that differ only by a hyphen or underscore?

Tags: python, conda

I am creating a new conda environment, and it is not clear to me why there are several required package dependencies that have the same name, but differ by a hyphen/underscore character. Here is an example snippet below from the package plan output. Thanks very much for any type of clarification. The only information I could find was that the *noarch* versions are platform independent, but it is still unclear then why there would be multiple versions required (and why the naming differs).

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
...
...
importlib-metadata-1.6.0   |           py36_0          50 KB
importlib_metadata-1.6.0   |                0          11 KB
...
...
prompt-toolkit-3.0.5       |             py_0         245 KB
prompt_toolkit-3.0.5       |                0          11 KB

...

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
...
...
importlib-metadata pkgs/main/linux-64::importlib-metadata-1.6.0-py36_0
importlib_metadata pkgs/main/noarch::importlib_metadata-1.6.0-0
...
...
prompt-toolkit     pkgs/main/noarch::prompt-toolkit-3.0.5-py_0
prompt_toolkit     pkgs/main/noarch::prompt_toolkit-3.0.5-0
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446485/

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716475/what-is-the-difference-between-prompt-toolkit-and-prompt-toolkit/61717003#61717003

Comment: @ARooks I don't think this is the same issue, as the question you linked is about pip and conda interoperability.

Comment: Thanks so much. The answer @cel linked to answered my question. I marked it as useful.